# jquery ajax post - json is returning but not working right

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, jquery

I've started the following skeleton for an ajax/post/update function I'm wanting to write in javascript (using jquery):

```
$.post("/gallery/resize",
  function (data) {
    alert(data);
    alert(data.complete);
    if (data.complete) {
      alert("done");
    } else {
      alert("blah");
    }
  },
  "json"
);
```

And the response script on the server is:

```
$return['complete'] = 'complete';
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($return);
exit;
```

The FireBug console shows that I get a JSON string in response - but the value of data.complete is 'undefined'. Here is the string from the server as reported by the FireBug (I also have a corresponding value/data pair under the JSON tab under the XHR display in the console):

```
{"complete":"complete"}
```

Any pointers on what I might've missed...

I am working on a localhost server - apache on ubuntu - if that makes a difference?

Comment: could you post the exact json string that firebug shows in the response tab of the xhr request?

Comment: have added the string as displayed in the FireBug console

Answer (score 5, accepted):

oh boy - turns out that I was a bit too trusting of the power of jQuery - I was missing a parameter in the $.post() method which may be optional unless you want to specify the other things.

the odd thing is that the callback works without the preceding data parameter being set - but it freaks out when you want to set the datatype (and must have the data and callback set).

So - the correct code for what I want would be:

```
$.post("/gallery/resize", "",
  function (data) {
    alert(data);
    alert(data.complete);
    if (data.complete) {
      alert("done");
    } else {
      alert("blah");
    }
  },
  "json"
);
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how jQuery parses JSON data, but it may be the JSON string is being evaluated incorrectly. If you enter `{"complete":"complete"}` in the FireBug console, it is interpreted as a block statement rather than an object literal (the `"complete"` property name is evaluated as a label). This is fixed by evaluating either `({"complete":"complete"})` or `{complete:"complete"}`, or using `JSON.parse` on `{"complete":"complete"}`. The quickest way to fix this would be to remove the `"json"` parameter from the `$.post` call and parse the data your self, like so:

```
$.post("/gallery/resize",
  function (data) {
    var obj;
    if (JSON.parse) {
      obj = JSON.parse(data);
    } else {
      obj = eval("(" + data + ")"); // obligatory eval() warning
    }
    if (data.complete) {
      alert("done");
    } else {
      alert("blah");
    }
  }
);
```

Incidentally, if you're debugging with Firebug, always try to use `console.log` instead of `alert` - it doesn't interrupt execution of the JS, and it gives much more informative JSON serialization than `[object Object]`

Comment: fair enough on the console.log

but according to jQuery's own manual page on $.post, you shouldn't need to parse the data - http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.post

Comment: well - it does move me forward... passing the value 'data' through JSON.parse() gets me a proper object now. weird

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$return = array('complete' => 'complete');
echo json_encode($return);
exit;
```

Comment: it doesn't make a difference - besides all documentation on PHP header and the content type header indicates it should be Content-type

Answer (score 1):

JSON data is like a javascript array. So you should access it the same.

Therefore, in the code you provided, you should access the entry "complete" this way instead:

```
data.items[0].complete
```

That should do the trick.

[You may look here](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.getJSON) for further jQuery/JSON information.

Comment: JSON is not like a javascript array - it is a condensed notation for JS objects to allow easy transfer of data - in may case 'data' is the object, and 'complete' should be a property of that object. Either jQuery or the browser is apparently supposed to parse the JSON to an object - and so I should be able to get the value of data.complete from my response.